# How to remove the 'Close' button from DispForm?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I see it is possible using code, but this is not an option for us at this time as it is not supported.

```
<style>

 .ms-ButtonHeightWidth
 {
 display:none;
 }

</style>
```

I use SPD2010.
thanks

Comment: what do u mean by adding code? the above style can be added into the css and applied to the master page.

Comment: I want remove the close button . I found this link http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/245fc63c-360e-4a13-917c-8b9ebed189e0

Answer (score 1):

I saw the link provided and the post suggests to add the style in a web part for the disp form.aspx. That would be the best approach since you can hide the button for just one disp form in a particular list. Otherwise, if you add the style in your custom css the button would be hidden on all the lists throughout the site.

There is one more option that you could try out for the particular list.

1. Open the site in SPD and go to the folder Lists.
2. Right click on the particular list that you want to modify and click on Properties.
3. On the opened List settings screen in SPD, you would be able to add a custom Form, by clicking on New on the right hand side.
4. Enter file name and Select Display Item form and set this as default.
5. On the newly created Form, right click and edit in Advanced mode.
6. Inside the PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass add the style `.ms-ButtonHeightWidth  {  display:none;  }`  and that should fix it.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks , but Does not allow to add new code in PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass

Comment: Add it like this -
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
.ms-ButtonHeightWidth  {  display:none;  }  
</style>
</asp:Content>

Comment: thanks.but when i use this code , i get error (
Web Part Error: Unknown server tag.)